# Trying to Call Python from C

Tags: python, c, visual-c++

```
#include <Python.h>

static PyObject* helloworld(PyObject* self)
{
    return Py_BuildValue("s", "Hello, Python extensions!!");
}

static char helloworld_docs[] =
    "helloworld( ): Any message you want to put here!!\n";

static PyMethodDef helloworld_funcs[] = {
    {"helloworld", (PyCFunction)helloworld, 
     METH_NOARGS, helloworld_docs},
    {NULL}
};

void inithelloworld(void)
{
    Py_InitModule3("helloworld", helloworld_funcs,
                   "Extension module example!");
}
```

I've been trying to extend Python with C and consequently have been trying to compile the above code in Visual Studio. However, I repeatedly get the following error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'python27.lib'
```

After adding python27.lib to the project I then get the following errors:

```
HiWorld.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Py_BuildValue
HiWorld.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Py_InitModule4
```

I've been stuck on this for quite awhile and would greatly appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code is correct, the best way to make it work is to use a `setup.py` file. For example, here's the code of the one I used when I created a hello world module:

setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

setup(
    ext_modules = [
        Extension("ext1", sources=["ext1.c"]),
   ],
)
```

Here, "`ext1"` would be substituted for your module's name, and '"ext1.c"' would be substituted for your C source file's name.

Then you run it from a terminal like such:

```
setup.py install
```

Just for further reference, here is my C source:

ext1.c:

```
#include "Python.h"

static PyObject *
hello_world(PyObject * self, PyObject * args)
{
    return Py_BuildValue("s", "Hello World!");
}

static PyMethodDef
module_functions[] = {
    { "hello_world", hello_world, METH_VARARGS, "Says Hello World."},
    { NULL }
};

void
initext1(void)
{
    Py_InitModule3("ext1", module_functions, "My additional Module");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a linking issue and the most common mistake is about forgotting that the Release profile and the Debug profile use different sets of symbols and, as consequence, can only link successfully against different versions of libraries; this means that in Debug mode you are supposed to provide `library-debugVersion.lib` and in Release `library.lib`.

I also do not use Visual Studio too much but i consider much more handy to put all the libraries that i need frequently in the common folder that is something like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\` so VS can automatically find the right library for you no matter the settings for single project are.